# MyBatis not loading with Oracle SYSDATE in mapping file

Tags: java, oracle, spring, mybatis

I have the following pretty basic mapping in one of my XMLs:

```
<select id="getUserAuthorities" parameterType="string" resultMap="resultGetUserAuthorities">
    SELECT AUTHORITY FROM BASIC_AUTHORITIES
    WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) = UPPER(#{username})
        AND (EXPIREDTADSTP IS NULL OR TRUNC(EXPIREDTADSTP) < SYSDATE)
</select>
```

With the above mapping, my application server fails on container startup (Spring) during the creation of mappers with the following error:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

It seems to fail on the sysdate, as if I remove

> OR TRUNC(EXPIREDTADSTP) < SYSDATE

then it works just fine.

Does MyBatis not support the Oracle SYSDATE field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an unescaped less than sign within your XML.

Comment: Thanks, completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the word "<" to ">". 
and you can change the sentence `TRUNC(EXPIREDTADSTP) < SYSDATE` to  `SYSDATE>TRUNC(EXPIREDTADSTP)`.
Maybe, the error message occurs because you didn't finish the bracket.